# popoverController not seguing

Tags: swift, segue, popover

Hi I have a popover view that is showing an array. I am wondering if there is a way that I could somehow segue back which item's in the array are selected.

```
 @IBAction func popOverButton(_ sender: UIButton)
{

    let controller = TableViewController()
    //This is just a regular tableViewController nothing special
     controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    // configure the Popover presentation controller
    let popController: UIPopoverPresentationController? = controller.popoverPresentationController
    popController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down]
    popController?.delegate = self
    popController?.sourceView = sender
    popController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    popController?.backgroundColor = .white
    self.parent?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { })

}
```

[Here is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qny4W.png)

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to create a delegate and when a cell is selected pass the selection back to the presenting view controller. Then setting up the UITableViewDelegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to call the delegate method. Something like this:

```
@protocol  PopoverOptionSelectionDelegate {
    func itemSelected(item:String);
}
```

Implement the method in your presenting VC

```
class PresnetingViewController, PopoverOptionSelectionDelegate {

    @IBAction func popOverButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let controller = TableViewController()
        controller.delegate = self //----Important---//
        //This is just a regular tableViewController nothing special
        controller.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        // configure the Popover presentation controller
        let popController: UIPopoverPresentationController? = 
        controller.popoverPresentationController
        popController?.permittedArrowDirections = [.down]
        popController?.delegate = self
        popController?.sourceView = sender
        popController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
        popController?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.parent?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: { })
    }

    func itemSelected(item:String) {

        //DISMISS YOUR POPOVER MAYBE AND DO SOMETHING WITH "ITEM" HERE
    }

}

class TableViewController,UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var delegate:PopoverOptionSelectionDelegate?

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        delegate?.itemSelected(self.itemsArray[indexPath.row])
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `weak var delegate: PopoverOptionSelectionDelegate?` to avoid a cycle

Comment: in itemselected how would I dismiss the popover VC and add it to another array

Comment: @SamR. you can add `var presentingVC = self.presentingViewController;

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: {()->Void in
        println("done");
         presentingVC.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
    });` in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath after you call `delegate.itemSelected`. And you can add the item to an array just like any other situation `self.otherArray.append(item)` in the `itemSelected` method.

Comment: Is this easier than going through nsuserdefaults do you think? and if someone were to dismiss the popover and call it again would the selected cells remain the same?

Comment: IT more of a matter of use than easiness. You definitely can but It really depends on how you want to use the popover selected option. NSUserdefaults is usually used to save an option or a app wide setting the user makes. If you want to pass the selected items back to the popover, you can do so by having an extra property i.e. `selectedItem` in your TableViewController class and set it right before you present the popover